# linearized KDV equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, dispersive-pde

Consider the PDE
$$u_t +4u_x +6u_{xxx} =0$$
for the function $u = u(x, t).$

(a) Determine for what wave speeds $c$ there exist bounded travelling wave solutions of $u$, and find the form of the solutions. (The solution is bounded if there exists constant $K$ such that $|u(x, t)| < K$ for all $x$ and $y$.

I am looking for some input as to whether my solution is sound.

**Attempt:**

We will make use of the following two facts.

(i) in the literature I have been using $c=\dfrac{\omega}{k}$

(ii) $|\sin(\alpha)|\leq1$

Given that $|u(x, t)| < K$ we want to find $|u_t +4u_x +6u_{xxx}|<k$.
First see that we have the following partial derivatives
\begin{align*}
u_t&=A\omega\sin(kx-\omega t)\\
u_t&=-Ak\sin(kx-\omega t)\\
u_{xxx}&=Ak^3\sin(kx-\omega t)
\end{align*}

For ease of notation let use set $\alpha = kx-\omega t$. Then making the proper substitutions we must show
$$|A\omega\sin(\alpha)-4Ak\sin(\alpha) + 6Ak^3\sin(\alpha)|<k.$$
Now see that,
\begin{align*}
|A\omega\sin(\alpha)-4Ak\sin(\alpha) + 6Ak^3\sin(\alpha)|&\leq|A\omega||\sin(\alpha)|+|-4Ak||\sin(\alpha)| + |6Ak^3||\sin(\alpha)|\\
&\leq|A\omega|+|-4Ak| + |6Ak^3|\\
&\leq A\omega+4Ak+6Ak^3\\
&\leq \omega+4k+6k^3.
\end{align*}
now see that
\begin{align*}
\omega=-6k^3-4k&\Rightarrow \omega=k(-6k^2-4)\\
&\Rightarrow\dfrac{\omega}{k}=-6k^2-4\\
&\Rightarrow c=-6k^2-4
\end{align*}
So, if we set $K=-6k^2-4$ we have a bound for $c$.